# Image stretching in landscape how to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Hi i developed view controller programatically in swift its working perfect in portrait mode while coming in landscape mode images are stretching and not adjusting, i used image XCassests to fix up the sizing issues.

let blahIMAGE = UIImage(named: "blah")

```
    myFirstButton.setBackgroundImage(blahIMAGE, forState: .Normal)

    myFirstButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 100)

    myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's exactly happening here is that the UIContentMode isn't getting changed when you are changing from portrait to landscape. What you need to do is ask the controller to redraw all of the elements when the device is turning to either of the sides.

```
self.view.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
```

Or otherwise, if you want only the image to be fixed, use:

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
```

Comment: thank you for idea, i will check it out

Comment: its not working i tried no change in output, any other option if possible pls

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: func colorButton(withColor color:UIColor, title:String) -> UIButton{
        let newButton = UIButton(type: .System)
        let blahIMAGE = UIImage(named: "Hotels")
        newButton.setBackgroundImage(blahIMAGE, forState: .Normal)
        return newButton
    }let subStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttonArray)
        subStackView.axis = .Horizontal
        subStackView.distribution = .FillEqually
        subStackView.alignment = .Fill
        subStackView.spacing = 40 let viewsDictionary = ["stackView":stackView]

Comment: fun colorButton method return me button, and that button have image which is in horizontal stack so my constraints are stretching them, if i take out the constraints its not showing anything, hope u understand it